# getting a "Cannot read property 'getFoodX' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, oop

So I am trying to write a basic Snake Game and getting an undefined error although I don't see anything wrong with my code after reviewing it. I am getting the same error for `this.apple.getFoodX` when removing the if condition causing the error with getFood.

```
class Game {

    constructor(canvas, extent) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.extent = extent;
        this.cellSize = canvas.width / extent;
        this.context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
        this.initGame();
        this.gameOver = false;
        setInterval(x => {
            this.loop()
        }, 350);
    }

    drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.moveTo(x1, y1);
        this.context.lineTo(x2, y2);
        this.context.stroke();

    }

    drawGrid() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        for (let i = 1; i <= this.extent; i++) {
            this.drawLine(i * this.cellSize, 0, i * this.cellSize, this.canvas.height);
            this.drawLine(0, i * this.cellSize, this.canvas.width, i * this.cellSize);
        }
    }

    newApple() {
        this.apple.create(this.extent);
    }

    getAppleX() {
        return this.apple.getFoodX();
    }
    getAppleY() {
        return this.apple.getFoodY();
    }
    getExtent() {
        return this.extent;
    }
    genFood() {
        this.apple.create(extent);
    }

    loop() {
        if(this.gameOver === false) {
            this.snake.update();
        }
        if(this.gameOver === false) {
            this.drawGrid();
            this.snake.draw();
            this.apple.draw();
        }

    }
    draw() {
        this.drawGrid();
        this.snake.draw();
        this.apple.draw();

    }

    initGame() {
        this.snake = new Snake([{x:7,y:8},{x:8,y:8},{x:9,y:8,}],this.cellSize, this.context, this.extent, 'ArrowRight');
        this.apple = new Apple(5,10,this.cellSize,this.context);
    }
    gameEnds() {
        this.gameOver = true;
    }
}

class Apple{
    constructor(x,y,cellSize,context) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.cellSize = cellSize;
        this.context = context;
        this.newApple = {x:0,y:0};
    }

    draw() {
        this.context.fillStyle = 'green';
        this.context.fillRect(this.x * this.cellSize, this.y * this.cellSize, this.cellSize, this.cellSize);
    }

    create(extent) {
        this.newApple = {x: Math.floor(Math.random() * extent),y: Math.floor(Math.random() * extent)};
        this.x = this.newApple.x;
        this.y = this.newApple.y;

        for(let i = 0; i < this.snake.snakeArray.length; i++) {
            if (this.newApple.x == this.snake.snakeArray[i].x && this.newApple.y == this.snake.snakeArray[i].y) {
                this.newApple = {x: Math.floor(Math.random() * extent),y: Math.floor(Math.random() * extent)};
                this.x = this.newApple.x;
                this.y = this.newApple.y;
            }
        }
    }
    getFoodX() {
        return this.x;
    }
    getFoodY(){
        return this.y;
    }
}

class Snake {
    constructor(snakeArray, cellSize,context,extent,pressedKey) {
        this.cellSize = cellSize;
        this.context = context;
        this.extent = extent;
        this.pressedKey = pressedKey;
        this.snakeArray = snakeArray;
        //this.snakeArray.push(startingPos);
        this.snakeHead = {x: this.snakeArray[this.snakeArray.length-1].x, y:this.snakeArray[this.snakeArray.length-1].y}; 
        document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
            this.handleKeyUp(event);
        });
    }

    handleKeyUp(event) {
        if (event.code === 'ArrowUp' || event.code === 'ArrowDown' || event.code === 'ArrowLeft' || event.code === 'ArrowRight') {
            this.pressedKey = event.code;
        }
    }

    update() {
        let newSnakeHead = {x:0,y:0};
        if (this.pressedKey === 'ArrowUp') {
            newSnakeHead = {x: this.snakeHead.x, y: this.snakeHead.y-1};
        } else if (this.pressedKey === 'ArrowRight') {
            newSnakeHead = {x: this.snakeHead.x+1, y: this.snakeHead.y};
        } else if (this.pressedKey === 'ArrowDown') {
            newSnakeHead = {x: this.snakeHead.x, y: this.snakeHead.y+1};
        } else if (this.pressedKey === 'ArrowLeft') {
            newSnakeHead = {x: this.snakeHead.x-1, y: this.snakeHead.y};
        }
        if(newSnakeHead.x === this.game.getFoodX() && newSnakeHead.y === this.game.getFoodY()) {
            this.snakeArray.push(newSnakeHead);
            this.game.genFood(); 
        }
        else {
            this.snakeArray.shift();
            if(this.outOfBounds(newSnakeHead, this.extent) === true || this.snakeHit(newSnakeHead, this.extent) === true) {
                this.game.gameEnds();
            }
            else{
                this.snakeArray.push(newSnakeHead);
            }
            }
    }
    draw() {
        for(let i = 0; i< this.snakeArray.length-1; i++) {
            this.drawSquare(this.snakeArray[i].x, this.snakeArray[i].y, 'red');
        }
        this.drawSquare(this.snakeHead.x,this.snakeHead.y,'yellow');
    }

    outOfBounds(newSnakeHead,extent) {
        if(newSnakeHead.x > extent || newSnakeHead.x < 0 || newSnakeHead.y > extent || newSnakeHead.y < 0 ) {
            this.game.gameEnds();
            return true;
        }
    }

    snakeHit(newSnakeHead) {
            for(let i = 0; i< this.snakeArray.length; i++) {
                if (newSnakeHead.x == this.snakeArray[i].x && newSnakeHead.y == this.snakeArray[i].y) {
                    this.game.gameEnds();
                    return true;
                }
            }
    }

    drawSquare(x,y,color) {
        this.context.fillStyle = color;
        this.context.fillRect(x * this.cellSize, y * this.cellSize, this.cellSize, this.cellSize);
    }
}

const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
const game = new Game(canvas, '16');
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access the `game` object inside Snake class with `this` but it's not a part of Snake class. So I think, in your `update()` method inside `Snake` class, following statement is the culprit:-

```
if(newSnakeHead.x === this.game.getFoodX() && newSnakeHead.y === this.game.getFoodY()) {
            this.snakeArray.push(newSnakeHead);
            this.game.genFood(); 
        }
```

You can create a reference to your game in Snake constructor like:-

```
constructor(snakeArray, cellSize,context,extent,pressedKey,game) {
        this.cellSize = cellSize;
        this.context = context;
        this.extent = extent;
        this.pressedKey = pressedKey;
        this.snakeArray = snakeArray;
        this.game = game;
        //this.snakeArray.push(startingPos);
        this.snakeHead = {x: this.snakeArray[this.snakeArray.length-1].x, y:this.snakeArray[this.snakeArray.length-1].y}; 
        document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
            this.handleKeyUp(event);
        });
    }
```

and in your Game class:-

```
initGame() {
        this.snake = new Snake([{x:7,y:8},{x:8,y:8},{x:9,y:8,}],this.cellSize, this.context, this.extent, 'ArrowRight',this);
        this.apple = new Apple(5,10,this.cellSize,this.context);
    }
```

Pass additional `this` parameter. That will help you set the correct reference to the `game` property in your `Snake` class.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This fixed all errors. Now my snake is just not reacting to keypresses and not moving..